# How can I delete old entries in locales_source

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

Drupal 7. I have used the t() function to translate many string in different languages. I used English as default language, and added t('This is a new string') all around my module files, template files, etc.

The problem is that I have changed the original string names several times, and in some instances, I didn't delete the "duplicate" entries, so there is garbage. Is there a way of listing or retrieving all the t() strings that I added? Maybe comparing with a fresh Drupal installation and exporting a template *.po and using a program to compare the changes ?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

One way to get rid of unnecessary entries in `locales_source` is to run the following:

```
DELETE locales_source 
FROM   locales_source 
LEFT JOIN locales_target lt 
using (lid) where lt.lid is null;
```

To get an idea of what this will remove from the table, you could check using:

```
SELECT count( * ) 
FROM locales_source 
LEFT JOIN locales_target lt
USING ( lid ) WHERE lt.lid IS NULL;
```

I got the idea from : http://julian.pustkuchen.com/en/drupal-7-performance-blown-localessource-table

In my case, I had a lot of stale content in `locales_source`. I also had many pages where content was tagged as being translated, but the page included many call `t('...')` calls, which added unnecessary entries to the table. Long story short, I was able to safely remove over a million rows of data and site performance went from absolutely awful to humming along nicely.

YMMV, but it worked for me.

Comment: Looks like for D8 it should work also. Could You confirm, please ?

Comment: This is working for Drupal8 too